# exact string match in a table of sql server

Tags: sql, sql-server

In SQL server I have table with column name "filename", which contain value like "aaaa/bbbb/1_3.tif" , I want to do exact match with 1_3.tif only,

```
SELECT * FROM tablename WHERE filename LIKE '%1_3.tif%';
```

How to achieve this..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you want:

```
where filename like '%/1_3.tif'
```

The `/` "anchors" the pattern so it doesn't match `'11_3.tif'`.  The lack of `'%'` at the end means that there are no following characters.

If you wanted to extract the filename, you could use:

One method uses `string_split()`:

```
select t.*, f.last_part
from tablename t cross apply
     (select s.value as last_part
      from string_split(t.filename, '/') s
      where filename like '%/' + s.value
     ) f
```

Answer (score 1):

`_` is a special character in the `LIKE` expression. You either need to wrap the character in brackets (`[]`) or escape it:

```sql
SELECT *
FROM dbo.tablename
WHERE filename LIKE '%1[_]3.tif';

SELECT *
FROM dbo.tablename
WHERE filename LIKE '%1\_3.tif' ESCAPE '\';
```

Answer (score 1):

Here another approach by using tokenization via XML/XQuery.

It allows easily get to the last token, i.e. file name, in a fully qualified file path via `last()` clause.

**SQL**

```
-- DDL and sample data population, start
DECLARE @tbl TABLE(ID INT IDENTITY PRIMARY KEY, [filename] NVARCHAR(MAX));
INSERT INTO @tbl ([filename]) VALUES
(N'aaaa/bbbb/1_3.tif'),
(N'c:/temp/aaaa/bbbb/1_770.txt');
-- DDL and sample data population, end

DECLARE @separator CHAR(1) = '/'
    , @searchFor NVARCHAR(256) = N'1_3.tif';

WITH rs AS
(
    SELECT *
        , c.value('(/root/r[last()]/text())[1]', 'NVARCHAR(256)') AS [FileNameOnly]
    FROM @tbl
        CROSS APPLY (SELECT TRY_CAST('<root><r><![CDATA[' + 
          REPLACE([filename], @separator, ']]></r><r><![CDATA[') + 
          ']]></r></root>' AS XML)) AS t(c)
)
SELECT ID, [filename], FileNameOnly 
FROM rs
WHERE rs.FileNameOnly = @searchFor;
```

**Output**

```
+----+-------------------+--------------+
| ID |     filename      | FileNameOnly |
+----+-------------------+--------------+
|  1 | aaaa/bbbb/1_3.tif | 1_3.tif      |
+----+-------------------+--------------+
```